# Slim Framework: D.R.Y

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I am using the following code to use a route, but I will repeat the same code for a different route.

Question: What would be the best way to avoid repetition? I've tried using a method getParameters, but that wouldn't work because when I return the parameters I need to set them to a variable, which makes the code redundant. Or maybe I am looking it the wrong way.

I am trying to use "DRY"(Do not repeat yourself). Someone might change the parameter names so this is helpful.

```
$app->get( '/blog', function() use ($app){ //same code as below });


$app->get( '/link', function() use ($app){
$link = new linksApi();

//call question api


$username = $app->request()->params('username');
$company = $app->request()->params('company'); // tags
$follower = $app->request()->params('follower');    
$max = $app->request()->params('max');    
$date = $app->request()->params('date');    
$date_value = $app->request()->params('date_value');    
$oldest = $app->request()->params('oldest');    
$counts = $app->request()->params('counts');    
$sorts = $app->request()->params('sorts');    
$counts = $app->request()->params('counts');    
$format = $app->request()->params('format');    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not wise to use it if you worry about performance, but here it goes:

```
$routes = array(
    'username',
    'company',
    'follower',
    'max'
    // ...
);

foreach($routes as $r) {
    ${$r} = $app->request()->params($r);
}
```